# Загрузка файла через python на сервер

Tags: python

В общем на севрере стандартная схема приема запроса с файлом на php, мне надо отправить файл с консоли на сервер, с пайтоном столкнулся в 1 раз, опыт только в php
можно пример плз

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import requests
>>> files = {'report.xls': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files=files)
>>> r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
True
```

Comment: @stribogaaaa Спасибо вам за наводку на замечательный сайт [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org)!

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, вот такой пример нашел с подгрузкой модуля chilkat 
верно ли тут все? или можно проще и удобней?

```
import chilkat

upload = chilkat.CkUpload()

#  Specify the page (ASP, ASP.NET, Perl, Python, Ruby, CGI, etc)
#  that will process the HTTP Upload.
upload.put_Hostname("www.chilkatsoft.com")
upload.put_Path("/receiveUpload.aspx")

#  Add one or more files to be uploaded.
upload.AddFileReference("file1","dude.gif")
upload.AddFileReference("file2","pigs.xml")
upload.AddFileReference("file3","sample.doc")

#  Do the upload.  The method returns when the upload
#  is completed.
#  This component also includes asynchronous upload capability,
#  which is demonstrated in another example.
success = upload.BlockingUpload()
if (success != True):
    print upload.lastErrorText()
else:
    print "Files uploaded!"
```

Comment: врядле проще нужно :)

Comment: upload.put_Path("/receiveUpload.aspx")
Это файл приема? например upload.php обработчик